# How two agents communicate undirectly through a memory sharing in multi agent systeme

Tags: shared-memory, data-sharing, multi-agent

Communication between agents in multi agent system MAS can be done directly with messages changing ( send and receive ), or indirectly throug a memory sharing so agents can write and read informations from the memory.
I have to implement the second communication type and i have no idea... :(
thank you for ur help.

Comment: You're going to need to add some more detail for the community to be able to assist with your question. Can you clarify what it is you find confusing with more specificity?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid indirect communication, the most used way for agents communication is using FIPA-ACL protocol.

You can see more about FIPA-ACL on their web-site: http://www.fipa.org/repository/aclspecs.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks for ur interests, here i m in obligation to have an concurent access to objects in memory with all agents, so lets take a example: I have two agents A,B, all they have to work on a list of object( let s say a list of integer named yassine that are initialized on 0) , if the two agent find the yassine[x] == 0 the agent A change it to 1 , and B to 2 ; but if it s different to 0 the Agent pass to the next : ( conccurent access to the same objects in memory ).
If i use FIPA-ACL communication each agent work on it's list, and we have two lists in memory.
I hope i clarify my question??